# Dynamic Component Presentation 'type' in Page source (TCDL Tags in source )

Tags: 2011-sp1, tcdl, sdl-tridion

There is a Home Page in CMS in which I inserted two different Component Presentations.

For one Component presentation the Property: `Component Presentations based on this Component Template will be` is set to `Publish as a Dynamic Component`. TemplateID: tcm:200-78003-32

[image]
And, for the other CP, this property is set to `Publish Embeded on a Page`
[image]

However, when Previewing the page Or when ran in Template Builder, the Source seems confusing.

```
    <!-- HTML HERE... --><br/>
    <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:200-154146" 
          templateURI="tcm:200-78003-32"
     xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL"><br/>
    <!-- HTML HERE... --><br/>
    <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:218-12172" 
          templateURI="tcm:218-11777-32" 
         xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL"><br/>
```

Please note that I removed the CleanUp Template, so to see the TCDL tags.

Why the `type=Embeded` is there for Dynamic CP ( First TCDL Tag above ) ? Isn't it should be `type="Dynamic"` ? Under what conditions will the type be dynamic ?

Is there any thing I need to Edit in the DCP so that the correct `type="Dynamic"` is there in the TCDL Tag above ?
I was expecting that DCPs will be retrieved at runtime on Pages at server side using the `ComponentPresentationAssembler`. Seems like here the HTML generated by the DCP is not retrived at runtime but is just sticking to the page itself like the Embedded CPs.

[ SDL TRIDION 2011 SP1 ]

Comment: I think the embedded DCP behavior might be different in preview/template builder. Compare to the filesystem or broker database to see how the references are handled there.

Comment: Thanks Alvin. I will check the filesystem/broker databases to examine the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, Investigated on content delivery server, file systems, DB and got it working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Content Delivery side, The page published had below Asp.net kind of Custom Server Control Tag:

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation PageUri="tcm:200-15454-64" 
         ComponentUri="tcm:200-15439" TemplateUri=" tcm:200-78003-32" />
```

as also checked, the config file `cd_deployer_conf.xml` was having below properties

```
<TCDLEngine>
<Properties> 
<Property Name=”tcdl.dotnet.style” Value=”controls“/>
<Property Name=”tcdl.jsp.style” Value=”tags” />
</TCDLEngine>
</Properties>
```

As investigated further, the above settings make the Deployer to generate the Asp.net based Custom Server Tags[  for Asp.Net websites.]

Moreover, this Custom Server Control `<tridion:ComponentPresentation .. />` is indeed fetching the HTML/ComponentPresentation from Broker Database as verified.

This control also seems to be using the `ComponentPresentationAssembler` class since removing the `<TCDLEngine>` properties from `cd_deployer_conf.xml` was generating Inline codes, the important line Found was

```
<% Response.Write(componentPresentationAssembler.GetContent(
                                "tcm:200-15439", "tcm:200-78003-32") %>
```

So it does seems like the Dynamic CT behaves differently in preview and publish as Alvin suggested.